# Identifying this 6-pin power connector

Tags: components, identification

I'm looking for a manufacture ID for this 6-pin SMD power connector.

Anything will help, even a category to dig through on mouser/digikey/fanell.

2 Vcc
2 gnd 
2 temp sensor

[image: Con 1]

[image: Con 2]

Comment: What is the pitch (distance between pins)?  Is there any writing molded into the white housing?  Can you give us an idea about the wire gauge (AWG) ?

Comment: thanks, pin spacing is 1.27mm  . 
wire gauge, i cant tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a lot like the Molex product "[Pico EZmate Wire-to-Board Connector System](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoezmate&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors)":

[image: Pico EZmate]

Molex has many other similar wire-to-board connectors, so yours may be different depending on pitch and wire gauge.

There are, of course, other companies that make similar products, such as [TE Connectivity](http://www.te.com/en/home.html) (formerly Tyco) or [Phoenix Contact](https://www.phoenixcontact.com).

Comment: the part is [molex 781725006](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0781725006_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml)
thanks so much